# Issues faced during ServiceStack Ugrade from 3.9.71 to 5.9.2

Tags: servicestack, idbconnection

ServiceStack Old Version: 3.9.71
ServiceStack New version: 5.9.2
.Net Framework: 4.6.1

We are facing quite a few issues while trying to upgrade ServiceStack. Could someone please help.
The predominant issue is as below:
CS0012    The type 'IDbConnectionFactory' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

We tried a number of methods suggested online, but were not successful. The following the methods that were already tried:
a. We uninstalled all instances of the older version and removed from Debug folder and installed the new version.
b. Cleaned the solution and restarted the Visual Studio after the installation.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that your project is not referencing ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll from the [ServiceStack.Interfaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Interfaces) NuGet package.

As this error appears to be a binary incompatible issue I'd recommend you individually re-add the NuGet packages so they are all referencing the same version of ServiceStack and that all your projects have project references to each other so that a full rebuild rebuilds all your projects and is not referencing and old compiled binary of your project referencing an incompatible version.

I would also recommend your project uses the [new MS Build project format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) which has more human readable references so it's clear that all references to ServiceStack are NuGet `<PackageReference/>` and reference the same version.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="5.9.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Server" Version="5.9.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

If it helps, you can view the source code of ServiceStack's .NET Framework Project Templates to compare against your own.

https://github.com/NetFrameworkTemplates/web-netfx